# Linked Server : How to set an exclusive lock on a remote table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

As I found, you can set a lock on your desired table within a transaction with :

```
begin tran
    select 1 from myTable
        with (tablock /*or tablockx to block even reads from table*/, holdlock) 
    -- do your work
commit tran
```

But when I run this code on a linked server table, the table still accessible from within linked server! Why? How I can set a lock on this remote table like my example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When trying to execute a transaction across multiple servers, you need to use [`BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-distributed-transaction-transact-sql) instead of `BEGIN TRANSACTION`.

If my understanding is correct, `BEGIN TRANSACTION` creates a local transaction by default. Under certain circumstances (for instances, if you're doing an `UPDATE` on a table on the remote server) this will be escalated into a distributed transaction. If you have `remote proc trans` turned on for the remote server, then things like running a remote stored procedure should also automatically escalate to distributed transactions.

Otherwise, the remote operation will follow the normal transaction rules as a standalone operation on the remote server - in this case, the `SELECT` would be in its own one-statement "local" transaction on the remote server, and the lock would be released when the `SELECT` completed.

You may also need to use [`SET XACT_ABORT ON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql).

And, (as you noted in comments), you'll need to be sure the [MS Distributed Transaction Coordinator service is on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32489207/2624611).

Comment: u said : "Otherwise, the activities on the other server won't be in a transaction."? are u sure?! i think the problem is just transaction cannot acquire exclusive lock on linked server!